# Are there any sources where you can see on what initial data the Midjourney neural network was trained

Tags: data-request, machine-learning

Is there somewhere in open sources some of the data on which this neural network was trained?
Also interested in DALL-E source dataset.
I think these datasets should be identical.
If someone has met or has information, please help.